# Arrays for Maze Algorithm not Storing Proper Values

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I have everything down in my maze solver, except for the fact that the `wasHere` array is storing the **solution** (which is supposed to be stored by the `correctPath` array). It is also missing marking the end square of the maze. All the `wasHere` array is supposed to store are the spots that the program has gone to in the maze. The `correctPath` array has all false values, which is totally unexpected. I am using the recursive method mentioned in *Wikipedia*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_solving_algorithm

This is my *Maze Solver*:

```
private static int[][] maze = {{2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2}, 
                               {2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2}, 
                               {2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2}, 
                               {2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}; // The maze
private static boolean[][] wasHere = new boolean[4][7];
private static boolean[][] correctPath = new boolean[4][7]; // Solution

private static int startX = 4;
private static int startY = 0;

private static int endX = 1;
private static int endY = 3;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Maze: ");
    printMaze(maze);

    solveMaze();

    boolean b = recursiveSolve(startX, startY); // Whether or not there is a solution to the maze
}

public static void solveMaze()
{
    for (int row = 0; row < maze.length; row++)
    {
        // Sets boolean arrays to false
        for (int col = 0; col < maze[row].length; col++)
        {
            wasHere[row][col] = false;
            correctPath[row][col] = false;
        }
    }
}

public static void printMaze(int[][] array)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++)
        {
            System.out.print(array[row][col]);

            if (col == array[row].length - 1)
            {
                System.out.print("\n");
            }
        }
    }       

    System.out.print("\n");
}

public static void printPath(boolean[][] array)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++)
        {
            if (array[row][col] == true)
            {
                System.out.print("1");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print("2");
            }

            if (col == array[row].length - 1)
            {
                System.out.print("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}

public static boolean recursiveSolve(int x, int y)
{
    if (x == endX && y == endY) // Reach end
    {
        System.out.println("The maze is solvable.");
        printPath(wasHere);
        return true;
    }

    if (maze[y][x] == 2 || wasHere[y][x] == true) // Hit a dead end or end up in same place (no solution)
    {
        return false;
    }

    wasHere[y][x] = true;

    if (x != 0) // On left edge or not
    {
        if (recursiveSolve(x - 1, y))
        {
            correctPath[y][x] = true;
            return true;
        }
    }

    if (x != maze[0].length - 1) // On right edge or not
    {
        if (recursiveSolve(x + 1, y))
        {
            correctPath[y][x] = true;
            return true;
        }
    }

    if (y != 0) // On top edge or not
    {
        if (recursiveSolve(x, y - 1))
        {
            correctPath[y][x] = true;
            return true;
        }
    }

    if (y != maze.length - 1) // On bottom edge or not
    {
        if (recursiveSolve(x, y + 1))
        {
            correctPath[y][x] = true;
            return true;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("The maze is not solvable.");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but why are you even asking this question when there's a java implementation on wikipedia?

Comment: @paulpaul1076 I am trying to translate it for the maze but it pops up incorrect results.

Comment: what do you mean by "translate for the maze"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your maze solver is working correctly.  The problem is that you were probably printing the values of the `correctPath` array **before** your recursive method had finished writing to it.

I assume that where you had the following lines inside the `recursiveSolve(int x, int y)` method:

```
    System.out.println("The maze is solvable.");
    printPath(wasHere);
```

... at some point, you tried to run it using the `correctPath` variable instead, right?  Something like this?

```
    System.out.println("The maze is solvable.");
    printPath(correctPath);
```

But that is too soon.  The `correctPath` array values are set **after** the recursive calls start returning from the end of the maze.

Instead, try moving the `printPath` call **after** the top level call to the `recursiveSolve` method inside your `main()`.  Like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Maze: ");
    printMaze(maze);

    solveMaze();

    boolean b = recursiveSolve(startX, startY); // Whether or not there is a solution to the maze

    // Put this here!  It will work as expected.
    System.out.println();
    printPath(correctPath);
}
```

If this doesn't quite make sense to you, then it probably means that you haven't quite grasped how recursion works.  Use a debugger to step through your program, as you should have done in the first place, and things should become clearer.